# Why does this code crash?

Tags: c++

The following code causes a stack overflow but I don't see why...

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "start";
    char bmp[1024][768][3];
for (int p = 0; p < 9000; ++p)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 768; ++j)
        {
            bmp[i][j][0] = 20;
        }

    }
}

cout << "Stop";


    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What does the outer loop (over `p`) do?

Comment: @nico oh, what character? I didn't realize it was.

Comment: @Silmaril89: decimal 20 is not a *printable* character, but well within the range for type `char`.  Maybe a typo, but 0x20 is an ASCII space character.  The OP should use `unsigned char` in order to get the full range of 256 values.

Comment: @Silmaril, `char` will hold any signed integer that fits in 8 bits -- from -128 to 127

Comment: This should be tagged a C++ since it uses `cout`.  The C language does not have C++ streams.

Comment: @Silmaril89: Well, in C++ you can assign any value between 0 and 255 to an unsigned char. 20 is not a printable character (like a letter or a number) but it's an absolutely valid statement.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII for more info.

Comment: `20` isn't a `char`, it is an integral literal which the compiler treats as an `int`.  However, `bmp[i][j][0] = 20;` is perfectly legal code, because `int` is implicitly convertible to `char`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would say it is likely because 1024 * 768 * 3 is `2,359,296` which is probably too big for the local stack.

You should instead allocate that on the heap.

Comment: The default stack is 1MB on Windows. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686774.aspx

Comment: @steaanv: Why use a std::vector for something as simple? You don't really need it.

Answer (score 2):

Allocating the int array crashes since it's bigger than the default Windows stack. Try changing it's size and you'll see that it crashes no more.