# Why is this code having a timeout?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this code crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877084/why-does-this-code-crash)

Please tell me whats wrong with the following code???Why is it crashing???

I cant store the collatz values in the array however if I want to print them individually it works perfectly.

```
#include <iostream>
long collatz(long);

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  long i=3,t[1000000],p;
  t[0]=0,t[1]=0,t[2]=0;
  for(i=3; i<1000000; i++)
  {
    p=collatz(i);
    t[i]=p;
  }
  cin.clear();
  cin.get();
}


long collatz(long n)
{
  long count=0;
  do {
    if (n%2==0)
    {
      n=n/2;
      count+=1;
    }
    else
    {
      n=((3*n)+1);
      count+=1;
    }
  } while(n!=1);
  return count;
}
```

Comment: You should try a debugger.

Comment: … timeout? What do you mean by that?

Comment: allocating a huge object like your `t[1000000]` inside the function body allocates it on the stack, and that causes problems.  Try putting it outside the function body as `static long t[1000000]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that stack allocation for:

`long t[1000000];` fails. So when you actually write into the array, it invokes undefined behaviour.

Allocate dynamically or use standard containers.

Answer (score 1):

Creating one million elements on the stack most likely results in a Stack Overflow (no pun intended!). This results in `i` being overwritten and thus causes an endless loop.